# React conditional rendering and mapping

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My `App`'s `return` looks like

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div className="App">
          <Sidebar />
          <Container className="container-comp" />
          {this.renderLoggingOutput()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Below the `Container` class, I try to conditionally render an output which is an array of strings.

The function looks like this:

```
  renderLoggingOutput = () => {
    if (this.props.status_msg === 'Success') {
      return (<div className="log-box">
        <div id="logging-output" >
          <h3 >Show Logging Output</h3>
          <div className='log-wrapper'>
            {
              this.props.logging_output.map((log, idx) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    {log}
                  </div>
                )
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      )}
  }
```

`this.props.logging_output` is a prop that I get from the redux state.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  status_msg: state.apiResponse.status_msg,
  logging_output: state.apiResponse.logging_output,
})
const mapActionsToProps = {
  updateStatusMessage: updateStatusMessage,
  updateServer: updateServer,
  updateLoggingOutput: updateLoggingOutput,
}
```

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(App);`

When I do this, I get an error saying that `this.props.logging_output` is not a function. It's weird because I thought `map` is usable for arrays.

Any help?

Comment: Please show the **exact** error message.

Comment: can you check if `logging_output` is really what you think should be?

Comment: It says `TypeError: this.props.logging_output.map is not a function`

Comment: console.log(logging_output) and see what the value is